# crawl small homepage with metadata.transfer and N:M-relationships

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

hi folks,

We use StormCrawler with elasticsearch to make an index of our homepage which consist of "old pages" and "new pages".
My Question in short:
If two pages A(old),B(new) link to page X, how to pass metadata from B to X?

My Question in long:
We relauched our homepage step by step. So at time we have pdf-Files which are reachable via only the old html-pages, via only the new html-page or on both ways.

For "order by" purpose we must mark all pdf-Files which are reachable by the new html-pages.
So we insert "newHomepage=true" to seeds.txt and "metadata.transfer/-newHomepage" to "crawler-conf.yaml": Fine :-)

But for the pdf-Files which are reachable from old !and! new html-pages, we now have a race condition: If our pdf-File is "DISCOVERED" from an old page this information (newHomepage=false) is in Status-Index and can not be overridden.
( StatusUpdaterBolt does not override documents, IndexerBolt does override by default).

To make the thinks more complicate: in our case a URL (at html-page) to a PDF is redirected two times, before the file is delivered.

So from my point of view we have two possibilities:

1. Start the crawler two times. First we only index our new pages (and all reachable pdf files), second we index our old pages.

   - --> Problems with new pages which are changed after crawler was started
2. Store "outbound_links" and use them to set "newHomepage" independently from the crawler

   - --> short times with wrong metadata in index

Any advice or other ideas?

Best regards
  Karsten

Answer (score 1):

thanks for sharing your problem and great to hear that you are using SC. This is an interesting and unusual use case.

Your analysis of the problem is correct. An intuitive approach would be to extend the default StatusUpdaterBolt so that it updates the metadata if a document already exists. You'd need to remove the part that does the check on whether the doc has a status of DISCOVERED.

This would slow things down, but since you are dealing with a single website, this should not have a massive impact.

You could push the logic even further by setting a new nextFetchDate if the document had been fetched so that it gets refetched and updated quicker in the doc index (as opposed to the status one).

Comment: OK, I like this solution. But how to ensure that the "newHomepage=true"-Status does win against a currently processed "newHomepage=false"-Status? --> support for version number in status index? (optimistic locking, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts)

Comment: Example ot the problem without version number in status-index: Let url_X be discovered with "newHomepage=false". Now ElasticSearchSpout has already read url_X but at exactly this time where the document for url_X is fetched the url_X is discovered again. This time with "newHomepage=true".
So StatusUpdaterBolt will first write url_X with "newHomepage=true" and status "discovered" but directly after this StatusUpdaterBolt will write url_X with status "fetched" and "newHomepage=false"

Comment: Correct link for optimistic locking in Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html

Comment: can't you use 2 different keys e.g. foundInOld and foundInNew? You could query for docs which have both or either of these tags?

Comment: Solution was to remove the "create" attribute for status "DISCOVERED"(like you recommended) but also use the "external version" feature of ElasticSearch. For Links to our "newHomepage" we use a higher version number, so a status-doc belonging to "oldHomepage" would be overwriten.